# How to define math values with js and then multiply those values?

Tags: javascript

I have to no idea how to set math values with javascript and then multiplied those values and I need help with that. I have this simple code:

```
<p>  Total:  <span class="total"> 2.35 </span> </p>
<p>  Stake: <span class="stake">  50 </span> </p>
<p>  Possible Winnings: <span class="posswin"> 117.50 </span> </p>
```

Where I need to define the values of 'total' and 'stake' with javascript manually. And then those 2 values to be multiplied so I get automatic the third value 'posswin'.
So if I set value of 'total' with javascript = 2.35, value of 'stake' is set with javascript = 50, then the script calculate the final result 'posswin'  2.35x50 = 117.50 is the third value.
And then the frontend result should look like:

Total:2.35
Stake:50
Possible Winnings:117.50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for your reference. you need to take couple of steps to embed javascript to your existing html document.

1. Create two files in the same directory. **index.html** , **script.js**
2. Copy the following content to each of the files

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>sample app</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>  Total:  <span id = "total_id" class="total"> </span> </p>
        <p>  Stake: <span id = "stake_id" class="stake"> </span> </p>
        <p>  Possible Winnings: <span id = "posswin_id" class="posswin"></span> </p>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
const total = 2.35
const stake = 50
const possibleWinnings = total * stake

document.querySelector("#total_id").textContent = total;
document.querySelector("#stake_id").textContent = stake;
document.querySelector("#posswin_id").textContent = possibleWinnings;
```

Comment: Note that it's not actually required to have the JavaScript separate from the HTML file - although you're strongly advised to have it separated, you could also insert the JavaScript inline by omitting the `src` attribute and have the JavaScript be inserted into the `<script>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate script.js file and copy this code

```
const total = 2.35    // what ever value
const stake = 50
const posWin = total * stake

document.querySelector('.total').value = total
document.querySelector('.stake').value = stake
document.querySelector('. posswin').value = posWin
```